# Position copied content within guides using a single PS Action

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, automation

I'm struggling to get the following done in a single action:

I have retouched full res TIFF's - each with a product shot on transparency background.  The products are in slightly different place in each image.  I need to resize the images to 725px x 680px and place the product within guides.

I managed to set up an action for guides, but how can I copy one layer with product (can I use it as a smart object?) onto the document with guides so it fits into guides precisely?

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!  I edited your question to highlight exactly what you're trying to do.  If I inadvertently changed the essence of the question, please feel free to fix my edit.  Please keep in mind that traffic here is generally lower on the weekend so it may take some time to get an answer.  Meanwhile, can you clarify your software? Your original title said "PS4" - do you mean Photoshop CS 4?

Comment: I do not believe an action can "scale to match guides". Scripting might be able to. A better alternative would be to place a Smart Object at the proper position, then simply edit the Snart Object contents.

Comment: If as you say "The products are in slightly different place in each image." - then I don't see how this can be automated with an Action.  Photoshop has no way of locating where an object is, nor does it know what an object in a photo is.  I'm not saying it couldn't be done, but it would require some kind of artificial intelligence or image recognition software.

Answer (score 1):

I too think that editing SmartObject is the way to go. change the content while the SmartObject stays in place. Maybe the resizing needs to be an extra action. But placing them all withing the SmartObject and changing the visibility (e.g. via Layer Comps) should work in my opinion. Layer Comps can also easily be exported or adressed via action.

Answer (score 1):

How about a different approach. Resize first.

Use an action to do this.

Covert layer to smart object.
Trim transparent pixels.
Resize image to 725px wide.

All images will now be the correct size, so just drag them into your guided document